# Return the content of a text file on localhost

Tags: java, android, runnable

I am trying to return the content of a text file on localhost (wamp server) as a string. I can read the text file but I cannot return a string because the function run of Runnable is a void. I'm working on Android Studio (that's why I'm using thread).

```
public String serverToString()
{
    String str;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://myIP/test.txt");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                str = in.readLine();
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    return str;
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible. you can not return any parameter from **asynchronous** methods.

Comment: Use volley to make server calls and make the call in the same class where you want to use that string, you can either have a global variable or a setter to pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Volley library would be preferred over raw Thread. Or AsyncTask

> but I cannot return a string because the function run of Runnable is a void

You can **pass** the result to a new method, though.

Define an interface

```
public interface ServerResponse {
    void onResponse(String msg);
}
```

---

Add a parameter

```
public void serverToString(final ServerResponse callback)
{
    String str;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://myIP/test.txt");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                callback.onResponse(in.readLine()); // This is the 'return' now
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

And instead of this

```
String response = serverToString();
```

Do this

```
serverToString(new ServerResponse() {
    @Override 
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // handle message
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working because I can't use callback inside the run function (it cannot be modified).

Comment: The parameter needs to be final... `serverToString(final ServerResponse`

Comment: Or, you should really read the Android documentation on networking and use the Volley library

Answer (score 0):

Advancing the the Cricket answer, I usually create an AsyncTask and inside it I define a callback interface.
The activity executing this task should implements this interface.
As an example of part of the code:

public class TeamUpdateTask extends AsyncTask, Object, TeamUpdateResponse> {

```
private TeamUpdateTaskCallback mListener;


@Override
public void onPostExecute (TeamUpdateResponse result) {
    if (exception == null) {
        mListener.OnTeamUpdateCompleted(result);
    } else {
        processException();
    }
}

 public void setListener (TeamUpdateTaskCallback listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public interface TeamUpdateTaskCallback {
    void OnTeamUpdateCompleted (TeamUpdateResponse response);
}
```

}

Hope it helps.